# Store Logged in user data in sonata admin bundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

In Sonata Admin Bundle, there is a registration form. Admin and super admin can create user using that registration form. Everything is working. But, now i want to keep trackwho (admin or super-admin id) created this user.So i want to store logged in user id.
in Commercant Entity:

```
/**
* Set createdBy
*
* @param integer $createdBy
* @return Commercant
*/
public function setCreatedBy($createdBy)
{
 $this->createdBy = $createdBy;

 return $this;
}
/**
* Get createdBy
*
* @return integer
*/
public function getCreatedBy()
{
  return $this->createdBy;
}
```

With this in sonata admin class i placed this code:

```
 public function preUpdate($commercant)
{
 $objUser = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    if(!empty($objUser)) {
        $commercant->setCreatedBy($objUser->getId());
    }

}
```

but nothing happen.

Comment: Hey did you ever get this working ? I'm looking for help if you don't mind it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
public function prePersist($commercant)
{
    parent::prePersist($commercant);

    $isSuperAdmin = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN');
    $isAdmin = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN');
    if($isAdmin || $isSuperAdmin) {
        $objUser = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        if(!empty($objUser)) {
            $commercant->setCreatedBy($objUser->getId());
        }
    }

}
```